# parameterise email "To" in node-red

Tags: node-red

I want to pass (actually want to loop in) email addresses (multiple) to email node. How I can achieve this. By default it taking only body of email as parameter and "TO" address is hard coded in node property file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rule for all the core Node-RED nodes (it should also be followed by other nodes, but not always) that says if you add an option in the config dialog then it can not be overridden by incoming msg properties.

If you leave the `To` field empty when configuring the node it should pick it up from the `msg.to` field on the incoming message.

If you have an array of addresses you should be able to use something like the slit node to break it up into separate message to pass into the email node (probably via a change node to rearrange the fields).

Comment: Can you pls hint how to create or which to pick for msg.to

Comment: That question doesn't make sense

Comment: trying to create a node with can pass msg.to to email node. not getting hit how to create a node which say msg.to and pass param to email node

Comment: There are many days to do it, either function or change node as a starter. But this is fundamental to his Node-RED works you'll have to just try